# Importing, Updating and Removing Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a number of taxonomy terms and some of them have sub terms that need to be updated.

Let me use a car for an example:

The Parent Term is Honda

Children Terms are: Civic, Accord, Fit

Honda
     Civic
     Accord
     Fit

I want to remove the sub terms and for every user who has selected Civic, I want their term to change to Honda.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: rename Civic to Honda.

Comment: I don't want Honda twice though as an option.

Comment: the first Honda isn't a vocabulary?

Comment: Sorry a term. Honda is a Parent term and Accord is a Child term.

Comment: humm have you tried deleting Civic to see what happens? maybe it defaults to its parent? (make a database backup first, of course)